# Mover texto tipo <a> html via css

Tags: html, css, brasil

sou novo na programação, e no momento estou tentando aperfeiçoar meu html/css. Tenho um problema bobo, mas acredito que mais pessoas podem ter essa mesma duvida.

Quero mover o tipo de dado `<a></a>`, quero movê-lo para à direita, mais ou menos como mostra a figura.
tentei usar o `margin-left: "";` mas apenas separa mais as letras.

[Imagem do objetivo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQAFz.png)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Web</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="texto-nav">
            Bem-Vindo
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">Perfil</a>
            <a href="">Sobre</a>
            <a href="">Ajuda</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
        
    <section class="home"></section>
</body>
</html>'
```

CSS:

```
body{
   background-image: url("img2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:black;
    background-position: right 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.nav{
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.texto-nav a{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold 30px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Um abraço à quem tiver a paciência de responder!

Comment: Está faltando informações na sua pergunta, mas tente usar .class{ float: left;
}

Answer (score -1):

Opaa, tudo certo?

O que pode ser feito pra resolver teu problema:

```
<nav class="nav">
        <div class="texto-nav">

            <div class="logo">
               Bem-Vindo
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
              <a href="">Home</a>
              <a href="">Perfil</a>
              <a href="">Sobre</a>
              <a href="">Ajuda</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.texto-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Coloquei uma div em volta do "Bem vindo" e dos links;
Usei flex box na div  pai (.texto-nav).

Espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score -3):

Olá! Tudo bom?
Você pode está editando no CSS a div que contém a tag , como:

#a{
      text-align: right;
    }
    


  
   Bordas
    copia

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).